# Iterate through JSON File in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, axios

I want to work with an JSON File in Javascript I got from my Flask server via a Axios Get-Request.

Its build like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "item": "[224,4,1,80,207,137,153,132]", 
      "name": "A1"
    }, 
    {
      "item": "[224,4,1,80,207,137,153,136]", 
      "name": "A2"
    }, 
    {
      "item": "[224,4,1,80,207,137,157,190]", 
      "name": "A3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I make my request with this and I can see the output in the terminal:

```
getInitialBoxesA() {
      const path = 'http://localhost:5000/getAllBoxesA';
      axios.get(path)
        .then((res) => {
          console.log(res.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line
          console.error(error);
        });
    },
```

**How can i iterate through this Array in Javascript?**

I tried `res.data[0]` or `res.data[0].item`

Comment: Iterate on `res.data.data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios returns the actual response body in `res.data`. Given your JSON, you would need to iterate on `res.data.data`.

```js
axios.get(path)
  .then((res) => {
    if (res.status === 200 && res.data?.data.length) {
      for (obj of res.data.data) {
        console.log(obj)
      }
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    console.error(error);
  });
```